# WordPress: Separating the content of a post into multiple pages and linking to them

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type in a WordPress theme called "reviews." On the template "single-reviews.php" there is some text, then a table full of specs, then a gallery, etc. I want to put the specs table and gallery each on a separate page. The specs and gallery would still have to somehow get the data for that review, though. Links to these sub-pages would be at the top of the review page.

I'm thinking that somehow a variable needs to get passed from the single review page to the specs page or the gallery page when a user clicks on either of those. My research isn't showing me a good way to do this, though. I think being inside of WP makes it more of a challenge.

My question is, is this possible, and has anybody done it before? If I can't get this to work, then I will use JavaScript to show/hide sections when they are clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You can still write PHP code in your templates, it doesn't have to be WordPress specific. Stick something in the URL and use `$_GET['something']` to decide what section of the post to display.

```
<a href="?display=gallery">Gallery</a> <a href="?display=specs">Specs</a>

<?php if (isset($_GET['display'] && $_GET['display'] == "gallery"): ?>
    Gallery HTML
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting an error about the parenthesis. I tried the following, but it doesn't get rid of the error: <?php if (isset($_GET['display'] && $_GET['display'] == "gallery")): ?>

Comment: I was missing the closing parentheses for the `isset()`, not hard to spot... you're not supposed to copy and paste anyway, just *understand* so you can write the code you actually need.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! The code was: <?php if (isset($_GET['display']) && ($_GET['display'] == "gallery")): ?>

Comment: Woah Dan who said I was copying and pasting? I'm still learning about PHP, so for me it was not that easy to spot. I played with it for a minute before leaving a comment but luckily played again and figured it out. Your comment came during that time!